# How to scroll form into view with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden div, which I toggle into view. The layer contains some filtering options and can be higher then the viewport. If the user scrolls, closes and reopens, then he should see the div from the top not where he left off. I tried `scrollintoview` without success.

How can I make the layer show always from top?

```
<script>
    $("#filter_button").on("click", function(){
        if ( $("#filter_button_inner").text() === "Zurück" ){
            $("#filter_box").toggle()
            $("#myform").scrollIntoView();
        }
        else {
            $("#filter_box").toggle()
            $("#myform").scrollIntoView();
        }
    });
</script>


<div id="filter_box" hidden >
    <form id="myform">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery

You can use the `scrollTop(0)` function in jQuery to scroll to top. It returns the current vertical position of the element if called without passing any variable. You can learn more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Here is how you can scroll to top once the page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

If you want to scroll the window at the start of your form then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($("#myform").offset().top);
});
```

## Javascript

In javascript you can use `scrollTo()` function to get the desired result. More details on [scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
```

You could even add smoothing to the scroll

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Hope this helps.